# Having issues with "setInterval/clearInterval" in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have this button:

```
<input name="start" type="button" value="Go!" onclick="activate()" />
```

followed by this javascript:

```
var timerID_;
function activate() {
    timerID_ = setInterval(someFunction, 300);
}
```

So this function is working alright, until I try to stop the interval. So I made a stop button:

```
<input name="pause" type="button" value="Stop" onclick="pause()" />
```

Accompanying javascript (in the same script):

```
function pause() {
    clearInterval(timerID_);
}
```

However, **this doesn't work** when I press the button. **THIS** works, however, where I just put the body of "pause()" into the onclick attribute:

```
<input name="stop" type="button" value="Stop" onclick="clearInterval(timerID_)" />
```

Just as I wanted it to, the second "stop" button pauses the interval. Anyone know why this is?

EDIT: here is the "someFunction" (not sure if it helps). Essentially what it is: http://spreeder.com. I take user (text) input and I display it word-by-word in the display box.

```
function someFunction() {
    var text = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var newText = text.split(" ");
    if (i == newText.length || newText[i] == undefined)
        pause();
    else {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = newText[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

ALSO: the error I get when I use pause(); *Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function*

Comment: what is the scope of the timerID_ variable?

Comment: @V31 just added it sorry, it's global

Comment: show your full code. Is that it?

Comment: @undefined I don't know, I'm just checking the page through my browser

Comment: your code must work, check your function someFunction.

Comment: added a fiddle and it is working for your original code

Comment: with the information you've given, there is no reason why it wouldn't work. You have something wrong that you haven't told us.

Comment: it is working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/Sr2C4/

Comment: @jhyap i get this error: 

*Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function*

when I try to use pause() instead of clearInterval.

Comment: Not the issue, but you use both ```timerID_``` and ```timerID```.

Comment: Do you have a form control on your page with `name="pause"`? That could cause an error like that. If there is an error telling you that the call to `pause()` is failing, that obviously means that the body of the `pause()` function is not executing. Can you please reproduce the issue for us in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Along the lines of what @JLRishe is saying, when you inspect ```pause``` in the console, what is it? What's typeof? etc.

Comment: @jpdstan you tried my jsfiddle and it prompts you that error?

Comment: @jlrishe Oh my god, you just fixed it. I changed it to `name="stop"` instead, to make it different from `pause()`, and it worked! I didn't think that mattered, woops! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is that browsers will create variables with the names of any form controls that are present on the page. So if you have a button like this:

```
<input name="pause" type="button" value="Stop" onclick="pause()" />
```

the browser will create a variable called `pause` that you can use to access this `input`, but it will mask (hide) the `pause()` function that you declared earlier. So when your event handler tries to call `pause()`, it will be trying to "call" your `input` object, which is not a function at all.

One solution, as you have found, is to keep the names of your functions different from the names of your controls. A better solution is to use unobtrusive JavaScript. This will not free you from making sure to keep your control names and function names different, but it should make your design cleaner and cut down on issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the `name` attribute and the name of the JavaScript function the same. What I originally did was:

```
<input name="pause" type="button" value="Stop" onclick="pause()" />
```

No error should occur should you change `name` to something else like `name="stop"`. I believe this is because the compiler would treat the `name` attribute like an object, and the `onclick` function would go to that first.